# Post objects as array to API in ionic2

Tags: angularjs, api, http-post, ionic2

I have an local array with values like this:

```
this.array = [
             {lat: '50.85034', lon: '4.35171', value: '50'},
            {lat: '50.850725', lon: '4.349685', value: '5'},
            {lat: '50.847582', lon: '4.330394', value: '25'},
            {lat: '50.848733', lon: '4.25422', value: '20'},
             {lat: '50.856965', lon: '4.221196', value: '10'},
            {lat: '51.054259', lon: '3.719366', value: '101'}
        ];
```

I want to post these values to my API.
So I need to do something like this:

```
 postObjectsArray()
    {
        var Array = {lat: ...., lon: ..., value: ..., id:...};
        var url = 'MyUrl';
        this.http.post(url, Array).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((response) => 
        {
        console.log("Success")
        });    
    }
```

But how can I put my local values into that new Array to post them?

I've tried something like this:

```
for (var i; i < this.array.length; i++)
{
   var Array = {lat: this.array[i].lat, lon: this.array[i].lon, value: this.array[i].value}, id:"..";
}
```

But how can I automatically increase the id? Because I need to give an ID with the post also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
let array = [];

for(var i in this.array){
    let tmp = this.array[i];
    tmp.id = i;//assigning the index as the id as it autoincrements itself ;-)
    array.push(tmp);//pushes the new object into array variable.
}
```

PS : I have changed "Array" to "array" as Array is a reserved variable (used to denote the Array javascript class);